# Firebase Email Verification

Tags: email, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm quite a noobie at Firebase. I'm asking for a sort of step by step guide to setup email verification.

Currently, my app uses basic email password login. I want users to be verified so I'm hiding content based on a user's emailVerified property. I'm calling the .sendEmailVerification() and it sends to the current user's email but, whenever I click the link in the email it says the link has expired or someone has used it, this also doesn't change the property. I suspect it has something to do with the api manager. I currently have my website hosted to the built-in Firebase hosting URL.

Based on this link in the docs (which refers to a similar function but not the exact one): https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sendPasswordResetEmail

p.s. I can't find anything regarding this exact function in the docs.

I think I need some sort of listener at the link of the email or on my website?

Thanks in advance, any answers are appreciated.

Comment: There is a default handler for these mails, which you can override if you want. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: I'd like to stick to the default ones. I just don't understand how they work. Could you explain or send me a link in the docs? Thanks.

Comment: Since email verification isn't available on Android yet, the reference documentation that you found is the only thing available at the moment. Sorry I don't have anything better to offer.

Answer (score 0):

there could be an issue with your browser api key. You may have some referrer restrictions on it. This could cause the misleading error (code expired or used) to occur. Either fix that issue or generate a new one in the Google console.